# in jquery, what does $.each mean?

Tags: jquery

what does the following mean?

```
$.each(json.results, function(i, item) {
    ...
}
```

I kind of understand the other parts of the line, but if you could explain that as well, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the parameter values and what they mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.each` provides a simple iterator and it will execute the callback function once for each element in the array.

For my examples, lets assume:

```
var json = {
   results: [1, 2, 3]
};
```

In addition to using the parameters (`index, item`), the `this` variable in each callback can be used to reference the current item.

**UPDATE**: This example changed to show use of the other parameters:

```
$.each( json.results, function(index, item){
   console.log(this + " " + index + " " + item);
});
// Outputs:
// 1 0 1
// 2 1 2
// 3 2 3
```

The first parameter is the **index** of the current item in the loop. It is a zero based index. The *second* parameter is the item of the current iteration. You can use `this` or the variable, but the variable comes in handy in situations like this:

```
$.each (json.results, function(index, item){
   // this == number
   // item == number
   $('div').click(function(e){
      // this == div
      // item == number
   });
});
```

Additionally, there are a few controls you can use similar to the `break` and `continue` statements.

If you want to `continue` or `next` at any point, use `return true;`

```
$.each( json.results, function(i, item){
  if(this == 2) return true;
  // do something else
});
```

If you want to `break`,  use `return false;`

```
var f;
$.each( json.results, function(i, item){
   if(this == 2){
      f = this;
      return false; // exits the iterator
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It just means you want to do something with **each** result found in `json.results`. Within the curly-braces, the current result you're handling is known by `this`, so you could do something like:

```
var json = { 'results':{'name':'jonathan', 'age':'26'} };

$.each(json.results, function(i,o){
  alert(this);
  // First iteration : 'Jonathan'
  // Second Iteration: '26'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$.each is basically an iteration idiom, similar to javascripts:

```
for (x in container)
```

except it iterates over values, instead of keys (or indices in the array case).

Comment: what goes in i and item, and how does it know what to put there?

Answer (score 0):

It iterates over the members of an object. An example:

```
var obj = {
    alpha : 'A',
    beta : 'B',
    3 : 'C'
};

$.each(obj, function(key, val) {
    console.log(key);    // alpha, beta, 3
    console.log(val);    // A, B, C
    console.log(this);   // A, B, C
});
```

Edit: Actually the above is a bad example of the context of `this`, because if your value is a string or number, it's converted from the literal ("C") to an object (new String("C")), but for other things (functions, elements, arrays, etc) it's untouched.